# Set Glassfish to not use any Digest Algorithm

Tags: java, glassfish, digest, jdbcrealm

I want my jdbcRealm to not use any Digest Algorithm in Glassfish. I want the jdbcRealm to compare against the database without converting password with any algorithm.

My password in the database is MD5 and I convert the user's password to md5 in java code and then use the code:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance ();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext (). GetRequest ();

request.login (username, md5Password);
```

So can I remove the Digest Algorithm so my jdbcRealm compare plain text without any algorithm?

I know I can send the user's password in plain text and the jdbcrealm will do the job for me, but I want to try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yo can

Set **Digest algorithm** `none`